# Decypher ES6 const destructuring declaration

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, destructuring

Can someone help me decypher this ES6 statement?

```
const {
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated,
    items: posts
  } = postsByReddit[selectedReddit] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }
```

I pulled it from the Redux async example - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/containers/App.js#L81

Comment: What parts of it do you understand and which not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is simply declaring three [constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), getting them from similarly named properties on an object if it is non-empty, otherwise get them from an object literal that acts as default values.
I trust that you are confused over the object like syntax rather than the const keyword.

**`var|let|const { ... } = ...`  is an *object destructuring declaration*.**

**`var|let|const [ ... ] = ...`  is an *array destructuring declaration*.**

**Both are short hand for "break down right hand side and assign to left hand side".**

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can be done on array or object using different brackets.
It can be part of a declaration or as stand-alone assignment.

```
const { isFetching } = obj; // Same as   const isFetching = obj.isFetching
var [ a, b ] = ary;         // Same as   var a = ary[0], b = ary[1]
[ a ] = [ 1 ];              // Same as   a = 1
```

For object destructuring, you can specify the property name.
For array, you can skip elements by leaving blank commas.
Destructuring can also form a hierarchy and be mixed.

```
const { items: posts } = obj;        // Same as   const posts = obj.items
var [ , , c ] = ary;                 // Same as   var c = ary[2]
let { foo: [ { bar } ], bas } = obj; // Same as   let bar = obj.foo[0].bar, bas = obj.bas
```

When destructuring `null` or `undefined`, or array destructure on non-iterable, it will throw `TypeError`.
Otherwise, if a matching part cannot be found, its value is `undefined`, unless a default is set.

```
let { err1 } = null;                // TypeError
let [ err3 ] = {};                 // TypeError
let [ { err2 } ] = [ undefined ]; // TypeError

let [ no ] = [];                // undefined
let { body } = {};             // undefined
let { here = this } = {};     // here === this

let { valueOf } = 0;        // Surprise! valueOf === Number.prototype.valueOf
```

Array destructuring works on any "iterable" objects, such as [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), or [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).
Of course, these iterable objects can also be destructed as objects.

```
const doc = document;
let [ a0, a1, a2 ]  =  doc.querySelectorAll( 'a' ); // Get first three <a> into a0, a1, a2
let { 0: a, length } = doc.querySelectorAll( 'a' ); // Get first <a> and number of <a>
```

Finally, don't forget that destructuring can be used in any declarations, not just in function body:

```
function log ({ method = 'log', message }) {
  console[ method ]( message );
}
log({ method: "info", message: "This calls console.info" });
log({ message: "This defaults to console.log" });

for ( let i = 0, list = frames, { length } = frames ; i < length ; i++ ) {
   console.log( list[ i ] ); // Log each frame
}
```

> Note that because destructuring depends on left hand side to specify how to destructre right hand side,
> you cannot use destructring to assign to object properties.
> This also excludes the usage of [calculated property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in destructuring.

As you have seen, destructuring is a simple shorthand concept that will help you do more with less code.
It is [well supported](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Node.js, and Safari,
so you can start learn and use it now!

> For EcmaScript5 (IE11) compatibility, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler#readme) transpilers
> can turn most ES6/ES7 code into ES5, including destructuring.
>
> If still unclear, feel free to come to [StackOverflow JavaScript chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-go-gotta-try-catch-em-all).
> As the second most popular room on SO, experts are available 24/7 :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an additional response to the already given. Destructuring also supports default values, which enables us to simplify the code:

```
const {
  isFetching = true,
  lastUpdated,
  items = []
} = postsByReddit[selectedReddit] || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
var isFecthing;
var lastUpdated;
var posts;

if (postsByReddit[selectedReddit]) {
  isFecthing = postsByReddit[selectedReddit].isFecthing;
  lastUpdated = postsByReddit[selectedReddit].lastUpdated;
  posts = postsByReddit[selectedReddit].items.posts;
} else {
  isFecthing = true;
  items = [];
}
```